# Not able to get WebSphere environment variable in Java

Tags: java, environment-variables, websphere

I've set the environment variable under `Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Environment Entries`

My Property name is region and value in dev.

I'm reading this property value like below:

```
String environment= System.getProperty("region");
```

But I'm getting null, what I'm doing wrong here? I tried to set the variable under this path as well: This also returning null - how can I read the environment variable in Java?

```
Environment > WebSphere Variables
```

I'm using WebSphere version 8.0.0.3

Comment: Did you restart the server after creating the env var?

Comment: Yes I did - couple of times but no luck :(

Answer (score 3):

Environment entries on the server's process definition are set as OS-level environment variables, not Java system properties. It's the equivalent of calling "set region=dev" on the command line before starting your JVM. Two potential approaches:

1) Use System.getenv() instead of System.getProperty() - getenv() is the method used to retrieve environment variables.

2) Instead of defining the property as an environment variable on the process, define it as a system property in the Process Definition -> Java Virtual Machine panel. You can either create a new System Property or add it to your generic JVM arguments as a -D option ("-Dregion=dev").